# DMZ config on RV082 router

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, router, dmz

We are connecting 2 offices with a dedicated point to point connection.  Both offices have the Cisco RV082 router.  In both offices, the routers are being used for internet on the WAN1 port.  This model has a WAN2 port, which can be configured as Dual-WAN or DMZ.  Dual-WAN appears to be for load balancing and fail-over.

I am planning on configuring WAN2 in DMZ mode on each router for our point to point connection.  In one office, the WAN2 port will have to be a private IP (192.168.177.1), and in the other office it will be a public IP (this is due to some other technical reasons i dont need to get into here).

My question is will this setup work?  Do i need to worry about assigning a private IP to the DMZ port?  Do I need to change the router from "gateway" mode to "router" mode?

I am adding routes to each RV082 so that the networks can talk.

I have called Cisco support and this model is out of warranty.  I also posted on the Cisco forum, but have received no help so far.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of point to point connection? Typically these involve CSU/DSU's which would require a router with different hardware specs than those RV082s you have. It sounds like you are trying to setup a VPN when you already have a dedicated connection.

Comment: It is a point to point with TW Telecom.  We have an ethernet hand-off in the San Diego location, so the RV082 can handle that. On the China side we have an E1 connection.  This is going to be connected to a Cisco 1921 router, and that will be connected via the ethernet port to the RV082.  We do have a VPN currently in place, but it is too slow due to the China firewalls.  The point to point will bypass the China firewalls so it will be much faster.

Comment: _The point to point will bypass the China firewalls so it will be much faster._ We did that once in a very large firm, it took about two months before we got a visit from members of the China embassy. After that visit, it took about 5 seconds for our legal department to have us shut down the connection.

Comment: Oh that's not good news. This is a pretty small company so hopefully they will fly under the radar.

Comment: Mainly I just want to find out if the RV082 router will be able to handle traffic to the 2 WAN ports.  Even though WAN2 is in DMZ mode, I am hopeful the device will look at the routing table and direct packets to the appropriate WAN port - WAN1 for internet, WAN2 for the LAN on the other side of the point to point.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the answer here in case anyone else runs into this.

This is not possible because the RV082 router has to either be in "gateway mode" or "router mode".  If it is in gateway mode, then the router is doing NAT, and the DMZ port will not route to another LAN.  If it is in router mode, then there is no NAT so the internet will not work.  But in router mode, the DMZ routes correctly to the other LAN.

We ended up adding a second router and the configuration is working.